# jquery input field focusout div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, focus

In script below: 
I am creating like a select option droplist,

But, if I use `focusout` event on text id after my selected text val event does not work!

Any alternative solution?

focusout event in block comment

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        
        //droplist toggle
        $('#text').click(function(){
         $('.droplist').toggle();
        });
        
         // text move to input field
         $('.droplist p').click(function(){
          var selected = $(this).text();
          $('#text').val(selected, $('.droplist').hide());   
         });
          
        // input field foucsout
        
        /*$('#text').focusout(function(){
         $('.droplist').hide();
        });*/
         
 });
```

```css
 #text{
        width:200px;
        height:35px;
        padding-left:10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-bottom:3px;
  }
 .droplist{
        width:200px;
        background-color:#D8D8D8;
        border-radius:4px;
        padding:5px;
        position:absolute;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family:arial;
        font-size:15px;
        display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    

</head>
<body>
<div style="margin:20px;">
 <input type="text" id="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Select Option" />
 <div class="droplist">
  <p>option one</p>
  <p>option two</p>
  <p>option three</p>
  <p>option four</p>
  <p>option five</p>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My first question is... Why? First, that div with P elements should be a list (ul and li), or better yet, a select. Make the form properly, and use jQuery UI to create styleable dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.val()` for setting the value only. Then hide the list.

```
$("#text").val(selected);
$(".droplist").hide();
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

You should use proper markup for the dropdown

```
<select class="droplist" name="droplist" id="droplist">
    <option>option one</option>
    <option>option two</option>
    <option>option three</option>
    <option>option four</option>
    <option>option five</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you can't make more styling of proper dropdown select option.

Answer (score 0):

you can use setTimeout() function because javaScript as besoin de temps pour l'execution de $('.droplist p').click();

```js
$(document).ready(function(){       
  //droplist toggle
  $('#text').focus(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.droplist').toggle();
  });

  // text move to input field
  $('.droplist p').click(function(){
    var selected = $(this).text();
    $('#text').val(selected,$('.droplist').hide());
  });
  // input field foucsout
  $('#text').focusout(function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      $('.droplist').hide();
    }, 100);
  });
 });
```

```css
 #text{
        width:200px;
        height:35px;
        padding-left:10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-bottom:3px;
        }
 .droplist{
        width:200px;
        background-color:#D8D8D8;
        border-radius:4px;
        padding:5px;
        position:absolute;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family:arial;
        font-size:15px;
        display:none;
 }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
     <script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    
        </head>
          <body>
   <div style="margin:20px;">
    <input type="text" id="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Select Option" />
    <div class="droplist">
     <p>option one</p>
     <p>option two</p>
     <p>option three</p>
     <p>option four</p>
     <p>option five</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
        </html>
```